# PyWPS FirstProcess

Tags: wps, pywps

I'm new in GIS and i'm starting to use pywps. I write [THIS](http://wiki.rsg.pml.ac.uk/pywps/First_Process) process but doesn't work. It returns this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pywps-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/pywps/Wps/Execute/**init**.py",
>   
> line 387, in **init**
>       self.consolidateInputs()
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pywps-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/pywps/Wps/Execute/**init**.py",
>   line 547, in consolidateInputs
>       raise pywps.MissingParameterValue(identifier)
>  **MissingParameterValue: < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>**
>   < ExceptionReport version="1.0.0"
>   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1
>   http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
>     < **Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="text"/**>

How can i fix this?

Comment: Hi, have you tested also the GetCapabilities and DescribeProcess request?

Comment: Yes, I tested and it seems alright...

Comment: Can you post the Execute request? It seems that you are not providing the "text" parameter.

Comment: request:
http:// localhost/cgi-bin/pywps.cgi?VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=Execute&SERVICE=WPS&IDENTIFIER=firstprocess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the datainputs. Take a look [here](http://wiki.rsg.pml.ac.uk/pywps/Introduction#KVP_Execute_request) for an example using KVP request.
You can also test the WPS service using the QGIS WPS plugin.

Comment: added the following &DataInputs=[text1=Marco]
and it worked
thanks!

Comment: Hi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.